# intel xdk set button width

Tags: css, intel-xdk

This should be such an easy thing. 
I'm writing my first Intel XDK app.
I have a "login" button that defaults to 100% (nearly) of the screen.
I want to make it narrower.
I've added a class with width at 50% and I've tried all kinds of stuff but I can't figure out how to make that stupid button narrower, or for that matter, higher, which is another thing I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand someone is working on adding width and other options to App Designer for cases like this, but unfortunately it's not out yet.  In the meantime, you can try to construct a very specific CSS rule so that it might be higher priority than whatever rule is currently setting it's width. It might also help to set both width and max-width.  Adding `!important` if necessary, though no one likes to use that if they can avoid it.